# Is there a difference in generating Secret Key in Java (SecretKey Interface) and forge?

Tags: javascript, java

I have a code for encrypting and decrypting in Java as such

```
public static String decrypt(String strToDecrypt, SecretKey secretKey) throws Exception {
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
    return new String(cipher.doFinal(base64Decode(strToDecrypt)));
}

 public static String encrypt(String strToEncrypt, SecretKey secretKey) throws Exception {
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
    return base64Encode(cipher.doFinal(strToEncrypt.getBytes("UTF-8")));
}
```

I tried to encrypt the data in forge js, and decrypt it using Java. All I get is

> Given final block not properly padded. Such issues can arise if a bad key is used during decryption.

```
  function aesEncrypt(data, secretKey) {
    var cipher = forge.cipher.createCipher('AES-ECB', secretKey)

    cipher.start()
    cipher.update(forge.util.createBuffer(data))
    cipher.finish()

    return forge.util.encode64(cipher.output.data)
  }

  function aesDecrypt(data, secretKey) {
    var decipher = forge.cipher.createDecipher('AES-ECB', secretKey)

    decipher.start()
    decipher.update(forge.util.createBuffer(forge.util.decode64(data)))
    decipher.finish()

    return decipher.output.data
  }
```

Is there a way to solve this?

Below is the way I generate my key. It is 32 length alphanumeric string.
The secret key is sent in the request itself (Symmetric enc).

```
SecretKey secretKey = AESEncryptionUtil.generateSecretKey();

public static SecretKey generateSecretKey() throws Exception {
        String secretStr = RandomGenerator.getAlphaNumericString(32);
        log.info("Generated secret key : {}", secretStr);
        byte[] decodeSecretKey = base64Decode(secretStr);
        return new SecretKeySpec(decodeSecretKey, 0, decodeSecretKey.length, "AES");
    }
```

The data is then encrypted. Now in JS, it is done as below

```
 function generateSecret(length) {
        var result = ''
        var characters =
            'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789'
        var charactersLength = characters.length
        for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength))
        }
        return result
    }


let aesEncryptedData = aesEncrypt(data, generateSecret(32))
```

I tried to debug it. I get the plain secret key as it is. The signature is also verified. But the data is not decrypted. I am confused if the Java's **SecretKey** Interface behaves differently, as in JS I use the plain secret key itself, while in Java I use the **SecretKey**.

Comment: How about presenting us two running examples (for Javascript and Java) that is showing as input plaintext, the value of  of SecretKey and the ciphertext/encrypted text on Javascript-side. The Java-program should show how you use the ciphertext and key [from Javascript] and what is the result of decryption. This is "debugging in use" and it will increase the chance for a helpfull answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem will be (without seeing more code with a full running example) that you need to use the same generated secretKey on both side (encryption and decryption). As you simply use the output of generateSecret(32) as input for your aesEncrypt-function you do not have access to the **same** key on decryption side.

```
let aesEncryptedData = aesEncrypt(data, generateSecret(32))
```

This is even more important when changing the platforms (javascript to Java). Below you find an example code in Java that takes the data of your encryption part (Javascript) and uses it for decryption.

**Security warning**: the code is **UNSECURE** as it uses AES in unsecure mode **ECB**. The codes does not have any exception handling and is for
educational purpose only.

output:

```
Is there a difference in generating Secret Key in Java (SecretKey Interface) and forge?
generatedSecret:  Mwhq5YXBY6d7zUUbQbVxsJeXvuOz7Sqp
aesEncryptedData: 2TxS64Eku0yO7Na7WwEWinnVwkzrbv2yTIdRA/cW5VURtuTdCyud0Bo4orxP1+ky
decryptedString:  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

code:

```
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.Base64;

public class MainSo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Is there a difference in generating Secret Key in Java (SecretKey Interface) and forge?");
        String generatedSecret = "Mwhq5YXBY6d7zUUbQbVxsJeXvuOz7Sqp";
        String aesEncryptedData = "2TxS64Eku0yO7Na7WwEWinnVwkzrbv2yTIdRA/cW5VURtuTdCyud0Bo4orxP1+ky";
        SecretKey secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(generatedSecret.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), "AES");
        String decrypt = decrypt(aesEncryptedData, secretKey);
        System.out.println("generatedSecret:  " + generatedSecret);
        System.out.println("aesEncryptedData: " + aesEncryptedData);
        System.out.println("decryptedString:  " + decrypt);
    }

    public static String decrypt(String strToDecrypt, SecretKey secretKey) throws Exception {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
        //return new String(cipher.doFinal(base64Decode(strToDecrypt)));
        return new String(cipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(strToDecrypt)));
    }
}
```